# How to create order_id on firebase for razorpay? I am using react-native with firebase for mobile application

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, razorpay

I tried to provide uuid of users as order_id but then i read that it should be different every time. So, I tried to provide a random generated uuid as the order_id from my front end but then it only redirected to the payment page the first time and after that it threw an error: "id doesn't not exist" If somebody can help, Thank you in advance!

This is the document razorpay has provided for reference: https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/react-native-integration/standard/android/

But it would help if Creating order_id was explained in terms of react native.

Comment: hey, can you tell me how did you implemented this in your app?

Comment: the id should be created on the backend and then fetched and passed on the frontend

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use UUID as an order id because it would not help
you must have to generate an order from Razorpay API. in response that will send you a server-generated order id

https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order

```
fetch("https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    amount: 50000,
    currency: "INR",
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((order) => console.log(order));
```

in response the created order looks like

```
{
  "id": "order_EKwxwAgItmmXdp",
  "entity": "order",
  "amount": 50000,
  "amount_paid": 0,
  "amount_due": 50000,
  "currency": "INR",
  "offer_id": null,
  "status": "created",
  "attempts": 0,
  "notes": [],
  "created_at": 1582628071
}
```

Comment: How are we passing the [YOUR_KEY_ID]", "[YOUR_KEY_SECRET]" here ?